# Recover contacts from Galaxy S2 when saved to an email

Tags: contacts

If I saved my contacts to an email on my Samsung Galaxy S2, and my email account was deleted on my phone, is it possible to recover my contacts?

Comment: If they're saved to your account then can't you just add it to your phone again or export the contacts from it? It sounds like you wouldn't need to "recover" anything, just retrieve them from the email account.

Answer (score 0):

Only if your email was sync'ed before you deleted the account from your phone. Check from a PC in the email account you used has the message in "Sent" folder (or inbox if you sent to yourself).